# curl video seekbar not working

Tags: php, curl, video-streaming, seekbar

I have the code in which I used the curl for getting video address and video run as well but code doesnt allow me to forwarding the video

My view code is like :

```
<video id="videos" width='300px' height='200px' controls>
    <source src="video.php" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

Here I can play the above video but seekbar(forwarding the video) is not working properly

I am very glad if anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include more information about your PHP code? This doesn't give us enough information.

Comment: Hello I am having a some videos but I dont want to show video name thats why I am calling video.php file in which we use curl and we show that file. You can refer following temporary url for showinig this : http://rsoftsystem.in/permission2/view.php

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script serving the video needs to set the HTTP `Accept-Ranges` header and needs to honor the `HTTP_RANGE` that is requested. That should be enough.

You haven't posted any of the PHP code for `video.php` (or `image.php` which you included in your example), so I can't be 100% sure this will do exactly what you are looking for.

This is a decent example of what I think you are trying to do: http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

This is the important part:

```
$this->start = 0;
$this->size  = filesize($this->path);
$this->end   = $this->size - 1;
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

    $c_start = $this->start;
    $c_end = $this->end;

    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];

        $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
        exit;
    }
    $this->start = $c_start;
    $this->end = $c_end;
    $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
    fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
}
else
{
    header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
}
```